# Merge 2 arrays after specfic some item of array of objects javascript

Tags: javascript

Lets have a look at an example.

```
var arr1 = new Array({name: "lang", value: "English"},
                     {name: "age", value: "18"},
                     {name: "address", value: "north"});
    
    var arr2 = new Array({name : "mobile", value: '543'},
                         {name: "email", value: "test@gmail.com"});

    I need to merge those 2 arrays of objects and create the following array:
    after "lang" item only merge arr2
    
    var arr3 = new Array({name: "lang", value: "English"},
                         {name : "mobile", value: '543'},
                         {name: "email", value: "test@gmail.com"}
                         {name: "age", value: "18"},
                         {name : "address", value: 'north'});
```

If merge 2 arrays means arr2 merged with at last of arr1; i want merge specific item

Comment: `arr3 = [...arr1]; arr3.splice(1, 0, ...arr2);`

Comment: take a look at [`.splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)

Answer (score 2):

```js
var arr1 = new Array(
  { name: 'lang', value: 'English' },
  { name: 'age', value: '18' },
  { name: 'address', value: 'north' },
);

var arr2 = new Array({ name: 'mobile', value: '543' }, { name: 'email', value: 'test@gmail.com' });

var arr3 = arr1.splice(0, 1).concat(arr2).concat(arr1);

console.log(arr3);
```